# How to negate a regex pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

So I have a regex that identifies an invalid pattern for my input, I would like to be able to reverse it so that instead of matching invalid cases it matches with valid cases. Here is the invalid regex:

```
^(?=\d{6}$)(?:(\d)\1{5,}|012345|123456|234567|345678|456789|567890|098765|987654|876543|765432|654321|54321)$
```

Ideally to match positive cases it should ensure:

- 6 digits
- the same digit does not repeat 6 times
- it is not sequentially incrementing or decrementing by 1

I have tried replacing the non capture group with a negative lookahead, however as I'm not familiar with the finer syntax for regex I'm not positive if this is simply an input mistake or if I need to change the regex somewhere else

**EDITS**
While I know this could be handled by javascript I would like to handle it with regex to leverage the Foundations error handling

Comment: It's not clear to me why you cannot use `if`...

Comment: If you are looking to find everything that this would not match to, you can enclose everything with `!` before it to negate/reverse the expression

Comment: Can't you check if it's matched in javascript and write your code in the else part of it?

Comment: The pattern does not seem to find positive matches. Probably, all you want is `/^(?!(?:(\d)\1{5}|012345|123456|234567|345678|456789|567890|098765|987654|876543|765432|654321|54321)$)/`

Comment: @Betlista, Taha Paksu I've added a note for my preference to handle this with just the regex instead of javascript

Comment: @MikeTung would you be able to give an example of that? this invalid pattern still meets the 6 digit expectation so not everything that doesn't match this one would match my valid expecations

Comment: "it is not sequentially incrementing or decrementing by 1". Regex does not have math, so you would have to give all possibilities,

Comment: @PoulBak right, I believe I already list all possible sequences in the alternation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/(?=^(\d){6}$)(?!^\1{6})(?!^(?:012345|123456|234567|345678|456789|567890|098765|987654|876543|765432|654321|54321)$)^\d+$/
```

The regex uses `look ahead` and starts by checking there's `6 digits`. It captures the `last digit` which is used with a back reference to check, there's `not 6 of the same digit`. It then use a `negative look ahead` to compare with the list of invalid sequences.

Finally it matches the `6 digits`.

Comment: ok, I can see where this differs from my attempts, seems to work great. Thanks very much!